# Android Notification

Tags: android, annotations

My requirement is need to display notification,when upload is available.Each & every time go to new Activity, It check Upload is available.(Upload mean : IF there any changes happened in android db, then it indicate need to upload to actual sql server db).

See my code :

```
   uploadSize = new UploadActivity().getUploadTable();
    if(uploadSize > 0){
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.u);
        button.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

        long whenTo = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Notification n = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "", whenTo);
        n.tickerText = "TV Spored ++";

        String contentTitle = "I am expanded title";
        String contentText = "I am expanded text";
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
        // Put additional stuff into the created intent
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent, 1);
        n.setLatestEventInfo(this, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
    }
```

From the my code ,

1. it didn't show the on the top of the bar.
2. Is there any good solution is available for upload.

Please help me..

Thanks in advance.

Is there any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show Notification Call this method

```
private void triggerNotification(String s) {
        CharSequence title = "Hello";
        CharSequence message = s;
        NotificationManager notificationManager;
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService("notification");
        Notification notification;
                notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "", whenTo);

        // Intent notificationIntent = new
        // Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, null, context,
        // NotificationBariconExmp.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                null, 0);

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, pendingIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(1010, notification);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the [NotificationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html).

You can use this as a guide: [Creating Status Bar Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)